# Create my own OSRM for routing machine on leaflet

Tags: leaflet, routing, open-source-routing-machine

I am implementing the routing machine wich is leaflet extension for routing analysis but by default the routing in routing machine is for demo based on OSM data.I want my own route ;How I do to build my OSRM server for route and how I make route of public transport based on bus lines not roads .

Comment: I assume you have OSRM installed and working (if not, see its web site). You can clearly only import data in formats that OSRM is programmed for, so convert your data into one of those formats. I'd suggest OSM PBF.

Answer (score -1):

Public transport uses the same street networks as public transport.
Probably you need to refine what your asking.

Comment: Beside public transport I need to know how to set up a sample OSRM server for street explain me step by step because I dont know how .

Comment: Does this work>> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-osrm-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Now I have my OSRM working well on Ubuntu. I have posted another question concerning how to build my own pbf.osm file of routes to feed the OSRM server because, I use now the pbf.osm of the routes of the whole globe the file provided by the OSM geofabrik web site .I like to set my own pbf.osm file of my own routes that I want for example the public transport routes https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255176/pbf-file-for-routing-machine-server-leaflet

Comment: I might try XML?